# Modify a python code that generate ffmpeg script

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I found this interesting python code: https://gist.github.com/royshil/369e175960718b5a03e40f279b131788

this is to generate a ffmpeg with xfade. I need to change 2 paramethers: duration and offset in this part of the script:

```
    # Video graph: chain the xfade operator together
video_length += file_lengths[i - 1] - 0.25
next_fade_output = "v%d%d" % (i - 1, i)
video_fades += "[%s][%dv]xfade=duration=0.5:offset=%.3f[%s];" % \
    (last_fade_output, i, video_length - 1, next_fade_output)
last_fade_output = next_fade_output
```

I tried different way but i coudn't. I tried by changing 0.25 and 0.5 but the generate video is not as expected, i don't know if I should also change the number 1 that appear.

thanks

Comment: lets says i need to use duration 4 offset 2

Comment: You say you tried a different way, what was that? Please edit your question to include your attempt.

Comment: Is this a question of how to modify [Python's old string formatting scheme](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) or how to run FFmpeg for your specific needs? If the former, study the linked documentation. If the latter, post a complete (but minimal) parsed ffmpeg command with clear explanation on what you want to accomplish.